# Drupal duplicate alias for same node

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

Any of you guys know why drupal it's duplicating my url alias when save a new node?

```
$node->path = 'st.louis';
node_save($node);
```

But in my alias table I have  st.luis and stlouis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be because of Locale core module. I had the same problem, but when i disabled the Locale module the problem was gone.

You can observe the main cause of the problem. When you look into the duplicate url aliases you will find the difference between the original url alias and duplicate url alias. In the original url alias you will have `language = "` and whereas with new/duplicate url alias you will find `language = 'en'`.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Giri, the problem is that I need the locale module.

Comment: ok, hope I do answered your question